# Generate profile previews with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following dilemma. I want to generate profile previews from different websites such as facebook, twitter, github, stackoverflow, google plus, etc to put on the profile of the website I'm developing. An image may be fine.

I know I could probably use an iframe with the zoom hack to achieve a somewhat similar thing to what I want to do, however, I'm not sure if that is very optimal for mobile devices, as the website is responsive and loading other websites might be bad for data plans.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Here's an image so that you can understand what I'm trying to do:

[image]

The ones with the name of the social network are the profiles I want to create/generate according to the URL specified.

**EDIT**

To clarify what is the preview I would like to generate, it is a picture of the website, a portion that is significant (includes cover photo or profile picture), not the entire website, as this may look ridiculous because of the tiny size.

Comment: Previous of what? Their photos? Their entire profile pages?

Comment: Photoshop. Screenshot.

Comment: This content is generated dynamically. That means those URL's are pulled from a database and therefore it would be dumb and silly to screenshot and photoshop it @DOCASAREL

Comment: They all have `API`s then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is much more complicated than that. I agree that displaying an `iframe` for each social provider is not only not optimal but also an awful solution. Practically, it's not even gonna work unless the user is logged in all these providers within the current session.

Your (I believe) only solution is to register your app which is individual social provider in order to consume their APIs and allow your app to sign in on behave off the current user. That's how it works, the user must sign in to Facebook, Twitter, etc., give consent to your app to access their profile's info and only then you will be able to display profile information for this user. Cumbersome feature to implement I think.

By the way, `jQuery` has no native support to interact with social networks

Comment: I guess I'll figure a way to make web service to take screenshots and program the schedule with cron on my server. Maybe that'll work if not I'll just drop the idea and try to make something else.

Comment: @hsoto I kinda like your optimism, but your web service will fail for exactly the same reason I explained above...your service will not have a valid credential to authenticate with neither Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc...and as soon as your service tries to request protected information (such as a user's profile) the request will be denied. Why do you think it is so simple to get people's personal info?

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately i don't have the reputation for commenting so i have to do a partial answer here. i'm not sure about twitter or the other apps you are trying to include, but for facebook you can usually get the user's profile picture using the graph api. for example to get the profile picture:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user}/picture
```

maybe twitter and the others have a similar, programmatic way to get a profile picture? 
hope this helps.